# Can't load XmlReader into XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to load an `XmlReader` into an `XDocument` for easier manipulation. The XML is well formed and valid (I double checked). When I try and load it into the `XDocument`, I get an `InvalidOperationException`

> The XmlReader state should be EndOfFile after this operation.

the code to load this is

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
    var doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
}
```

I've included a sample of the XML that causes the problem. I can serialize and deserialize this class without a problem, but not load it. Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ForestView xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Forest>
 <TreeNodeView>
  <Level>Master</Level>
  <ID>39476b1f-e2f8-4d76-b82e-a5166899ad43</ID>
  <Name>Black Mesa</Name>
  <ServerIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ServerIPAddress>
  <ServerPortNumber>8000</ServerPortNumber>
  <ClientIPAddress>NA</ClientIPAddress>
  <ClientPortNumber>4000</ClientPortNumber>
  <Nodes>
    <Level>Server</Level>
    <NodeID>062c3e03-235d-4d7d-9b60-c6228c9cc89e</NodeID>
    <Name />
    <ServerIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ServerIPAddress>
    <ServerPortNumber>5000</ServerPortNumber>
    <ClientIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ClientIPAddress>
    <ClientPortNumber>4000</ClientPortNumber>
  </Nodes>
  <Nodes>
    <Level>Intermediate</Level>
    <NodeID>9bafdc9e-771e-42cf-8f03-e7e75a67a6d1</NodeID>
    <Name>Jen</Name>
    <ServerIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ServerIPAddress>
    <ServerPortNumber>8001</ServerPortNumber>
    <ClientIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ClientIPAddress>
    <ClientPortNumber>8000</ClientPortNumber>
    <Nodes>
      <Level>Terminal</Level>
      <NodeID>72509141-0ab8-45c1-8042-30afb233b4a8</NodeID>
      <Name>Mary</Name>
      <ServerIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ServerIPAddress>
      <ServerPortNumber>0</ServerPortNumber>
      <ClientIPAddress>127.0.0.1</ClientIPAddress>
      <ClientPortNumber>8001</ClientPortNumber>
    </Nodes>
   </Nodes>
  </TreeNodeView>
 </Forest>
</ForestView>
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this snippet. Could you post the code where you instantiate the XmlReader and call the ReadXml method?

Comment: Please show the code making the call, and show the full exception.

Comment: Please also show the code that you use to create that `XmlReader` that you pass to `XDocument.Load`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error implies that there is extra data after the reader has loaded what it thinks is an XML document.  Please verify that your XML file contains no data after the final closing element and that the `XmlReader` is initialized to read from the root element or start of the file, and nothing else.

Answer (score 41):

Quite late answer, in case somebody is having the same issue.
You can fix it by using `ReadSubtree()` on the reader, like:

```
public void ReadXml(System.Xml.XmlReader reader)
{
     var doc = XDocument.Load(reader.ReadSubtree());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another late answer, but I ran into a problem with the `reader.ReadSubtree()` workaround and this ended up working for my situation. The basic approach is reading into a string, then calling `XDocument.Parse()`:

```
XDocument doc;
var textReader = reader as XmlTextReader;
if (textReader != null)
{
    var xml = textReader.ReadOuterXml();
    doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
}
else
    doc = XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Comment: This solution returns me an error: 'This operation would create an incorrectly structured document'

Comment: Your XML might be bad in that case.